# How does processor know how much to read from the stack for function parameters (x64)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow

I have a small program running on x64 calling system function with a parameter long enough which means he will be pushed to function on the stack as I understand.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char command[] = "/bin/sh -c whoami";
    system(command);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I check in GDB what is happening I can confirm that my parameter is on the stack on 2 words.

[image]

I wonder how does the CPU know that it needs to read 2 words and not continue after. What delimit the function parameter from the rest ?

I am asking this question as I am working on Buffer Overflow and while I have the same situation on the stack, the CPU does only pick one word (/bin/sh ) instead of the 2 words I would like. Outputing `sh: line 1: $'Ћ\310\367\377\177': command not found`

[image]

Comment: To the compiler, the parameter to `system` is length-agnostic. It is a `const char*` e.g, the size of a pointer. How it is 'pushed' and how that is recouped, is dependent on a variety of things, but the "value" of that argument isn't the string buffer; it is a pointer to said-same.

Comment: And the string itself is 18 bytes long, including the nul-character terminator.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see that GDB resolved the command parameter as a pointer to address 0x7fffffffd330 on the stack. But how does it know it needs to read from 0x7fffffffd330 to 0x7fffffffd338 ?  and not from 0x7fffffffd330 to 0x7fffffffd340 ? In fact its is previewing the 0x7fffffffd330-0x7fffffffd338 range.

Comment: GDB is just displaying consecutive 8-byte addresses; the string _starting_ at d330 is the whole string, the string _starting_ at d338 is only the `-c whoami` part, and the the string _starting_ as d340 is only `i` plus the null terminator, which is also the _integer_ 0x69 as shown

Comment: Short answer: It doesn't. This is how format string attacks happen in C.

Answer (score 2):

> How does processor know how much to read from the stack for function parameters (x64)

The CPU does not know.  By that, I mean it does not receive an instruction that says "retrieve the next argument from the stack, whatever the appropriate size may be."  It receives instructions to retrieve data of a specific size from a specific place, and to operate on that data, or put it in a register, or store it in some other place.  Those instructions are generated by the compiler, based on the program source code, and they are part of the program binary.

> I wonder how does the CPU know that it needs to read 2 words and not continue after. What delimit the function parameter from the rest ?

Nothing delimits one function parameter from the next -- neither on the stack nor generally.  Programs do not (generally) figure out such things on the fly by introspecting the data.  Instead, functions require parameters to be set up in a particular way, which is governed by a set of conventions called an "Application Binary Interface" (ABI), and they operate on the assumption that the data indeed are set up that way.  If those assumptions turn out to be invalid then more or less anything can happen.

> I am asking this question as I am working on Buffer Overflow and while I have the same situation on the stack, the CPU does only pick one word (/bin/sh ) instead of the 2 words I would like.

The number of words the function will consume from the stack and the significance it will attribute to them is characteristic of the function, not (generally) of the data on the stack.

Comment: Note that `system(const char*)` only takes one arg.  It gets tokenized later, by `system()` to pass as args to `execve` (after `fork`).  So whatever the problem with the OP's code, getting `system` to take two function args in terms of the calling convention is not possible or something that makes sense.

Comment: Quite so, @PeterCordes.  That is the specific manifestation of "The number of words the function will consume from the stack and the significance it will attribute to them is characteristic of the function" that seems to be of interest to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Processors are very very dumb.  All of them.  This is like asking how do you steer a train...You do not.  It just follows the tracks.  The processor just follows the bits in front of it, if they are wrong or do something bad then the processor will crash just like a train will derail if the tracks are bad.

The size of a variable is not determined by the processor type, x86, arm, etc.  Nor for C is it determined by the language, the size of an int for x86 is not assumed to be one size.  Assumptions like that are bad.  The compiler author chooses for that compiler for that target.  And no reason to assume any two C compilers for the same target processor use the same sizes.

Likewise the compiler author ultimately decides the calling convention, what goes in registers what goes in stack, what order they are in the stack, what registers, etc.

The compiler author chooses also the alignment or not of the stack.

The compiler author chooses to use a stack frame or not or allows the user to choose, but within either choice, with or without still chooses how to use the stack or stack pointer.

The compiler author using their calling convention, their choices for the sizes of variables, etc then as part of the compilation process decide what instructions to use.  The instructions should be chosen base on their choices above.  So a two byte sized variable should be in the stack based on decisions made by the compilation relative to the stack pointer or stack frame pointer based on compiler choices and possibly user options.

The processor does not know, it simply sucks in bits and does what they say, if the compiler and assembler and linker have done their job, ultimately the programmers responsibility, then the processor will do what it is told, including reading the proper number of bytes for a certain item.

As beaten to death on this site, examining the stack for main() tends to be confusing as there is mysterious padding added, ideally you want to compile this in some other function name and see that.  Also compiler options may determine how the code is built, what instructions are used and how much stack if any.  Optimization levels.   No reason to assume any two compilers will generate the same code from some C source, likewise no reason to assume one compiler will produce the same code based on compiler options.

So where on the stack, how many bytes on the stack, etc is determined by many layers of you the programmer plus compiler, assembler, and linker.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) implemented for the function. By specifying none, you let the compiler decide, and it can go creative, sometimes even disappearing with any explicit `call` for the sake of branch prediction optimization, otherwise you can learn precisely what to expect from [numerous sources of documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) that specify how those calling conventions are supposed to work.